# Given an array length 1 or more of ints, return the smallest value in the array

Tags: python-2.7

Given an array length 1 or more of ints, return the smallest value in the array.
my_min([10, 3, 5, 6]) -> 3
The program starts with def my_min(nums):

Comment: Use builtin function: `min`

Comment: @falsetru And here is the reference for it: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min

Answer (score 0):

As [falsetru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2225682/falsetru) stated, you should use the built-in `min` function.

In your case, it is used like following: `min(iterable[, key])`.

For instance,

```
myarr = [3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7]
print min(myarr)
```

yields

```
1
```

Here you could find the full reference for the function: [2. Built-in Functions — Python v2.7.6 documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min).

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok? using C

`int def my_min(nums)`
`{`
`int i,min;`
`int min[N];`
`for(i=0;i<nums;i++)`
`{`
  `scanf("%d",&min[i]);`
  `if (i==0)`
  `{`
    `min=min[0];`
  `}`
  `else`
  `{`
    `if(min>min[i])`
    `{`
      `min=min[i];`
    `}`
  `}`
`}`
`return min;`
`}`

Comment: The question was about python 2.7